# Determine what files are being accessed by a process

Tags: linux

How would I find out all the files a particular process accesses?

I am using Ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[lsof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) will list open files and associated process IDs. It lists everything if no options are given.

There is an option, `-p`, to list open files for a single process. So for a process with PID 6714 this will list the files opened by that process:

```
    lsof -p 6714
```

To list only regular files [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) can be used to filter the output of lsof:

```
    lsof -p 6714 | grep REG
```

If it needs to be more robust than with grep then the `-F` option can be used, but then it becomes more complex. From the [lsof man page](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/lsof.man.html):

> When the -F option is specified, lsof produces output that is suitable for processing by another program - e.g, an awk or Perl script, or a C program.

It depends on your requirements.

Comment: I like to add '-b' to lsof, it'll go a little quicker. Also, I add 2>/dev/null before the pipe to grep.